# Why does not g++ or clang elicit a warning when truncating a non-const variable by assigning it to a variable of smaller type?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings, clang

Both clang 2.9 and g++ 4.1.2 will generate a warning when the variable *x* is declared constant in the code snippet below. However when *const* is removed, as it has been in the snippet, neither of the compilers generates a warning even when executed with the following parameters which are the strictest I know: "-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -ansi"

Why won't the compilers deduce and report the same warning since *x* isn't volatile and cannot possibly be modified before the type conversion?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned int x = 1000;
    const unsigned char c = x;
    const unsigned int x_ = c;
    std::cout << "x=" << x << " x_=" << x_ << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With *const unsigned int x = 1000;* g++ provides the message "*warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type*" and clang "*warning: implicit conversion from 'const unsigned int' to 'const unsigned char' changes value from 1000 to 232 [-Wconstant-conversion]*".

Is there any way to automatically detect this case without manually inspecting the code or relying on correctly designed unit tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For GCC, add the flag `-Wconversion` and you will get the desired warning. It's not a part of `-Wall` since so much code just ignores these types of things. I always have it turned on since it finds otherwise hard to debug defects.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! How come it isn't included in Wextra though? I thought Wextra was a catch-all for everything that didn't fit in Wall.

Comment: I don't know. It should be part of -Wextra (I think it should be part of -Wall actually).

Comment: @David: unfortunately `-Wextra` is far from being a catch all. Afaik, there is no flag in either gcc or clang that activates just about everything.

Comment: @MatthieuM. clang's `-Weverything`.  Though at this point in the future you probably know that by now haha

Comment: @RyanHaining: Yes, it was really cool when they introduced this flag as it allows one to work in black-list mode instead of white-list mode (the latter not allowing automatic discovery of new warnings).

Answer (score 2):

If it is a const the compiler can see its value and warn about the truncation. If it is not a const, it cannot, despite the initialisation. This:

```
const unsigned int x = 1000;
const unsigned char c = x;
```

is equivalent to:

```
const unsigned char c = 1000;
```

Comment: There's value range propagation pass for non-const variables, which should do the deduction..

Comment: Certainly I've seen GCC use immediate values in the code emitted for non-const integer variables that happen never to be changed, so to say that GCC "can't" see the value seems too pessimistic. Perhaps this particular warning phase can't see the value.

Answer (score 1):

I've run gcc with -O3 -fdump-tree-vrp, and what I see in the dump is:

```
std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> > (&cout, &"x="[0], 2);
D.20752_20 = std::basic_ostream<char>::_M_insert<long unsigned int> (&cout, 1000);
std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> > (D.20752_20, &" x_="[0], 4);
D.20715_22 = std::basic_ostream<char>::_M_insert<long unsigned int> (D.20752_20, 232);
```

i.e. it just inlines the constants 1000 and 232 in the cout statement!

If I run it with -O0, it doesn't dump anything, despite -ftree-vrp and -ftree-ccp switches.

Seems like gcc inlines the constants before it can emit the warnings...